# How to remove last layers of Inception model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I followed a forum from Github about removing the last layers of a pre-trained model. However it's not working for me; perhaps I did something wrong

I'm following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479) and here's my code. I thought all I had to do was `model.layers[-2].output` but it's telling me `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'summary'`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3


model = InceptionV3()
print(model.summary())

modele = model.layers[-2].output
print(modele.summary())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modele variable is only a layer. You have to do:

```
model = InceptionV3()
print(model.summary())

output = model.layers[-2].output
modele = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = output)
print(modele.summary())
```

Comment: Wow that's weird....What are some tips to better understand this? I think I could sit all day reading documentation but is there a strategy you could give?

Comment: It's keras functional API. You can learn more about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional